# Google Maps inside Bootstrap tab-content are

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a Google Map inside a Bootstrap content-tab ([this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs)). This is my code for the map:

```
<style>
#map_canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

this is where I place the map_canvas div:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    ...other divs here...

    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='contact'>
     <div class="row">
         <div id="send_email" class='span4 pull-right'>
          ...blablabla a form here...
         </div>
         <div id="information" class='span8'>
         <ul>...contact info...</ul>
         <div id="map_canvas"></div>       
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the divs:

```
$('#navtabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Really, nothing special about it. Yet for some reason the map is off to the side, and looks like this:

[image]

If I try and move it it just auto-fixes itself to be half-outside like in the picture. ommiting bootstrap.css solves the problem. Putting `#map_canvas` outside the content-tabs also solves the problem. Yet I can't tell exactly what's screwing it up.

It isn't related to the max-width issue [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps), since I'm using bootstrap is 2.3.2 which addresses it and includes these lines by default (adding them to my own css doesn't help either):

```
#map_canvas img,
.google-maps img {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

I tried playing with chrome developer tools and scanning the divs and its parents, I went over the `.tab-content` inside bootstrap css, I tried ommiting the entirety of the img attributes inside the bootstrap.css, I tried [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415803/google-map-inside-jquery-tab-issue) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635903/google-map-in-bootstrap-tab) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634008/twitter-bootstrap-google-maps) from SO, to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This post will probably solve your issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746698/postpone-google-maps-initialisation-until-after-bootstrap-tab-is-shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a hacky solution for this issue when this was happening to my map in a bootstrap modal.

When the the tab (or modal in my case) content has finished loading call:

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(MAP_OBJECT, "resize");
```

And optionally:

```
MAP_OBJECT.setCenter(center);
```

Admittedly, the map for a brief moment looks the way it does in your screen shot and then looks normal.

Sorry I don't have a definitive fix for you!

Comment: As I also mentioned in the question, I tried this already (tried it again after you answered as well), and it isn't working for me. Thanks for trying anyway, but do note that the problem is obviously css-related and *not* something to do with the javascript

Comment: turns out it isn't related to css. I just didn't bind it to the right event

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Joseph's solution will work if you'll bind to the `shown` event instead of `click`.

Comment: bind the `shown` event to what? To `setCenter` or to `$(this).tab('show');`?

Comment: you're right. It took me a whole while to get there because this is a project I kinda abandoned but thar she blows. I gave @JosephFeeney the correct answer because, well, he answered the question. You got +1 though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@freakycue was right. I needed to do Joseph's answer but bind it to the shown event.

This is what ended up working for me:

```
$("#navtabs a").on("shown", function(e) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(MAP_OBJECT, "resize");
});
```