# Postpone google maps initialisation until after bootstrap tab is shown

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've researched a lot and it seems like a lot of people have had the same issue as me here, but i cant figure out how to fix it.

Basically i'm initializing a google map inside a hidden bootstrap tab. When i click on the pill to make the tab visible, only a small section of the map is shown.

From what i gather this is because the map is being initialized in a hidden element. So i need to initisialise the map only after the tab becomes visible.

I've tried and i've tried and i cant get the code right. Any help would be grand - how do i cause the map to only be executed after the tab is visible?

Thanks in advance

```
<!-- this is the hidden tab-->
<div class="tab-pane map-pane" id="map<?php echo $country_slug; ?>">

<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-12">
      <div id="map-canvas" class = "map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--and here is the map which executes inside the hidden tab-->
    <!--how can i cause this script to delay execution until the tab is shown?-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.39813,114.10943),
       zoom: 8
    };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

        }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://bootply.com/102479

Add an id to your map tab link so it's easier to identify. Trigger a map resize event when the corresponding tab content is shown.

This way the map is only initialized once, which is not the case with the previous answer.

Note that you need to define the map variable outside of the initialize function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. in addition to triggering the resize event i also had to reset the center with: map.setCenter(point);

Comment: @MrUpsidown .. I implemented the same it working fine with two maps in two tabs but when I included the third tab the initialization script is triggering for the last written script and not for the middle tab.

Comment: Amazing answer, just what i needed!

Comment: That's how you post an answer! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to attach a handler to the Bootstrap tab show event..

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    initialize();
});
```

### Working demo: http://bootply.com/102241

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Makes much more sense than the way i was trying. Look forward to trying it out later

Comment: Is this really the best way? With your code, every time a tab is clicked (not only the map one) the map is initialized again...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myTab a[href="#location"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myTab a[href="#location"]').one('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    initialize();
});
```

Use **.one()** instead of **.on()**. This will prevent from reloading map again and again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it to center on each tab click.. but seems need to initialize everytime ...

@MrUpsidown any other way we can center the actual location without initializing everytime?

**Possible solution ..**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25347742/3752338

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap tabs (and carousels and modals) are initially set to display none, until they become active, so the parent element of your map has height / width of 0.

I had the same problem with Bootstrap3 as you. finally I ended up with the simple CSS solution.

```
.tab-content.tab-pane,
.tab-pane {
    /* display: none; */
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.tab-content.active,
.tab-content .tab-pane.active,
.tab-pane.active {
    /* display: block; */
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, no JavaScript tricks needed.

```
.tab-content.tab-pane,
.tab-pane {
    /* display: none; */
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.tab-content.active,
.tab-content .tab-pane.active,
.tab-pane.active {
    /* display: block; */
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551984/3072600