# How to include Google map to show places like hospital and restaurant in separate maps on same page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I am using this script to show the restaurant in the nearby area

```
<script>
var map_rest;
var infowindow;
function initialize() {
  var restaurant = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);
  map_rest = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('restaurant-tab'), {
    center: restaurant,
    zoom: 15
  });
    var image_hospital = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.myvirtualadmin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/location-place.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
            position: restaurant, 
            icon:image_hospital, 
            map: map_rest
        }); 
  var request_rest = {
    location: restaurant,
    radius: 1000,
    types: ['restaurant']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service_rest = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map_rest);
  service_rest.nearbySearch(request_rest, callback_rest);

}
function callback_rest(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker_rest(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
function createMarker_rest(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.creare.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/marker.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: placeLoc, 
            icon:image, 
            map: map_rest
        });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map_rest, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

If I include the second script and change the type to school or hospital,
  `types: ['restaurant']` the nearby location does not show in first map by all in the last script.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#rest" data-toggle="tab"> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"> </i>Restaurant </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#hospital" data-toggle="tab"> <i class="fa fa-hospital"> </i> Hospitals </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#school" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> Schools </a></li>
                                </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="rest">
                                     <div id="restaurant-tab" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:3px solid #acacac;"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="hospital">

                                    <div id="hospital-tab" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:3px solid #acacac;"> </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="school">
                                    <div id="school-tab" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:3px solid #acacac;"> </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

The bootstrap tab is not loading the other tabs with the maps.

*** Here I am testing these maps by putting the map div outside div*

So basically two questions, 
How to show the different places in different maps and how to use load the map in the tab that are not active as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postpone google maps initialisation until after bootstrap tab is shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746698/postpone-google-maps-initialisation-until-after-bootstrap-tab-is-shown)

Comment: Thanks!!! I already checked that but its not initializing .. I am having multiple maps in each tab ..

Comment: When including the third tab with a map, it is not initializing the second tab then .. else working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Include  bootstrap.js/ bootstrap.css, jquery.js and google map script**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Tab Load of Map</title>
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        html, body, .container, .tab-content, .tab-pane {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map-canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 480px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var map_rest;
    var infowindow;
    function initialize() {
      var restaurant = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);
      map_rest = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: restaurant,
        zoom: 15,

      });
        var image_hospital = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.myvirtualadmin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/location-place.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
                position: restaurant, // Position marker to coordinates
                icon:image_hospital, //use our image as the marker
                map: map_rest, // assign the market to our map variable
                title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places', // Marker ALT Text
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            }); 
      var request_rest = {
        location: restaurant,
        radius: 1000,
        types: ['hospital','school']
      };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service_rest = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map_rest);
      service_rest.nearbySearch(request_rest, callback_rest);

    }
    function callback_rest(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker_rest(results[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    function createMarker_rest(place) {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.creare.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/marker.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
                position: placeLoc, // Position marker to coordinates
                icon:image, //use our image as the marker
                map: map_rest, // assign the market to our map variable
                title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places', // Marker ALT Text
                //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map_rest, this);
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    <script>
    var map_atm;
    var infowindow;
    function initialize_atm() {
      var atm = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);
      map_atm = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('atm'), {
        center: atm,
        zoom: 15,

      });
        var image_atm = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.myvirtualadmin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/location-place.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
                position: atm, // Position marker to coordinates
                icon:image_atm, //use our image as the marker
                map: map_atm, // assign the market to our map variable
                title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places', // Marker ALT Text
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            }); 
      var request_atm = {
        location: atm,
        radius: 1000,
        types: ['atm']
      };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service_atm = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map_atm);
      service_atm.nearbySearch(request_atm, callback_atm);

    }
    function callback_atm(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker_atm(results[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    function createMarker_atm(place) {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/banking-icons-2/512/ATM-128.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
                position: placeLoc, // Position marker to coordinates
                icon:image, //use our image as the marker
                map: map_atm, // assign the market to our map variable
                title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places', // Marker ALT Text

                //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map_atm, this);
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_atm);
        </script>

    <script>
    var map_hos;
    var infowindow;
    function initialize_hos() {
      var hospital = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);
      map_hos = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('hospital'), {
        center: hospital,
        zoom: 15
      });
        var image_hospital = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.myvirtualadmin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/location-place.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
                position: hospital, // Position marker to coordinates
                icon:image_hospital, //use our image as the marker
                map: map_hos, // assign the market to our map variable
                title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places', // Marker ALT Text
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            }); 
      var request_hos = {
        location: hospital,
        radius: 1000,
        types: ['hospital']
      };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service_hos = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map_hos);
      service_hos.nearbySearch(request_hos, callback_hos);

    }
    function callback_hos(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker_hos(results[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    function createMarker_hos(place) {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/healthcare-and-medicine-icons-1/512/Hospital-128.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
                position: placeLoc, // Position marker to coordinates
                icon:image, //use our image as the marker
                map: map_hos, // assign the market to our map variable
                title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places', // Marker ALT Text

                //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map_hos, this);
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_hos);

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    flag_atm = 0;
    flag_hos = 0;   
        $(document).on("shown.bs.tab", '#atmtab', function (e) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map_atm, 'resize');
            if(flag_atm == 0)
            {
                initialize_atm();
                flag_atm = 1;
            }
        });
        $(document).on("shown.bs.tab", '#hospitaltab', function (e) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map_hos, 'resize');
            if(flag_hos == 0)
            {
                initialize_hos();
                flag_hos = 1;
            }
            //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_hos);
        });
    });
</script></head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1>Google Map Inside Tab Panel</h1>

                       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"> </i> Location on Map </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" id="atmtab" > <i class="fa fa-hospital"> </i> Hospitals </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab" id="hospitaltab"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> Schools </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                         <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:3px solid #acacac;"> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">

                                        <div id="atm" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:3px solid #acacac;"> </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                                          <div id="hospital" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:3px solid #acacac;"> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```